# Got a remote job offer, how do I know that it's legitimate?

Tags: job-offer, telecommute, international

Recently I was contacted by a company for a remote job offer for a Russian company (I am in India). I accepted that and I had a face-to-face meeting with one person from their team.

He asked for my Github account. He just asked about basics of a programming language and we had some related discussions about tech and frameworks, nothing tough.

I was offered position to join that company and received an offer letter (as a one page Word document) which asks me to provide my passport ID.

I have searched online they didn't ask about any money if it was scam. However I am not able to decide if it's a legitimate offer as this company doesn't have much info online.  During the Skype interview HR told me that it's a group on 11 people or so working remotely.

Following things I noticed:

- They have their own email domain (which is good but not hard to buy
  up business email for scammers)

**Question: What are the things that I should look out for (red flags)?**

***NOTE: This is my first application for a remote job***

Comment: What country are you in? What country is the job in?

Comment: @DavidK i am based in India , job is based in russian county(remote)

Comment: When you had your face-to-face meeting, did you go to the company's premises?

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause No someone from their team was in India for business purpose(as i was explained) ,it was in one of the costliest 5 star hotels in India.They do not have office in india

Comment: Please forgive my confusion.  Am I understanding correctly that you haven't discussed **pay**?

Comment: @Lumberjack sorry for that, No they have discussed pay(after some negotiation) and mentioned in it offfer letter. its not something unrealistic but a normal 50% increase from my current pay,

Comment: Did you ask how they are going to pay your salary?

Comment: @Ashishkumar "it was in one of the costliest 5 star hotels in India"- Anyone can have a casual meeting in the lobby of a fancy hotel and pretend that's where they're staying.

Comment: @DavidK yes thats true, that is the reason i am asking here if its even genuine?

Comment: @gnasher729 do companies not require passport ID if they are offering remote job? this is my first remote offer so i have no idea about it. But if i think i was in positionof offering job to someone remotely how do i have my confirmations? what documents other than passport ID would be suitable for this job

Comment: @scaaahu they said  ,they can transfer it to my bank account directly

Comment: I think it's insufficient to conclude that it's scam. My guess for the passport ID is that he needs to be able to report to the company that who will do the job and to whom the company will pay the salary. He cannot just say the person's name is Ashish Kumar. The boss would ask who is Ashish Kumar. With your passport ID, he can then say it's the Ashish Kumar with this passport ID.

Comment: Why is asking for passport number a "red flag"? For remote jobs, it is even necessary. What other ID proof could the company ask for, which they can expect foreign candidates from (almost?) every country to possess?

Comment: This has signs of a scam, but you can't conclude such without more information.  The fact they sought you out is a red flag to me, where you looking for a remote position?, where did they get your information?  Why are the interested in hiring someone outside their country, and just happened to find you?  If anything, they aren't trying to cheat you out of money, but cheat you out of work, and then decide not to pay you.  Realize that across countries, you have very little legal recourse if things go bad between you.

Comment: Do they mean MS Passport(the microsoft single sign on solution) or your official international travel documents?  Are they wanting a  copy of it or have you send the real thing?  If they want a copy I would contact the consulate services and ask them for their advice on that.

Comment: Recommend considering Personal Finance (Money.SE) if there's a real concern about it being a scam. They are incredibly good at identifying and breaking apart how the scam works (if it is one).

Answer (score 10):

Put some research in.

Google up the company name and see what's out there.

Additionally you should perform a search on the governmental russian business registry ([link](http://www.ved.gov.ru/eng/companies/)) to see if the company is registered and has a VAT number/tax registration number in Russia.

Look at the salary details - is it a proper salaried job, or is it commission or piece work.  Are they asking you to pay for "admin" or "arrangement" costs prior to you being employed?

Question why they need your passport number.

Do you have any colleagues who have gone through the same situation - what were their experiences?

Is the extra money worth the uncertainty?

Ask for references, what established companies have they worked for?  Contact them and ask whether your prospective employer is trustworthy.

[Further reading](https://www.thebalance.com/how-to-tell-if-a-job-is-really-a-scam-2062183)

Comment: There is nothing about the company on google other than their linked in profiles.which includes its employee details and those employee have stackoverflow accounts(some of them have high reputations like 2000 and up) i found after research i can confirm

Comment: 2,000 isn't a high reputation.  I have over 30,000 rep here and I'm an idiot.

Comment: also i do not have any colleagues who have gone through similar situation.

Comment: one important point to mention that the HR has a broken english ( even worst than mine)

Comment: Also - you should consider what the product of this company is. Does it make sense they are paying you "x" for this position? Is that unusually high for this type of position? What do they sell? Who do they sell it to?

Comment: @Christopher the product is a betting software that they are making and they went into great details about how are they implementing it .The Tech stack and all .the amount that they are paying is not very much high considering my current pay (40% increase).the position is for backend engineer.they sell it to no one. its their internal product

Comment: @Ashishkumar [Wait, is it 50% or 40% increase?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110609/got-a-remote-job-offer-how-do-i-know-that-its-legitimate#comment342590_110609)

Comment: @Draken my apologies its 40 percent increase for now and after a probation period of 2 months they said it will be increased to make it 50% or so.

Comment: @Ashishkumar Why does it matter that they speak broken English? The company is located in Russia and you are in India. There shouldn't really be an expectation that they speak English - it just happens to be the language you both can communicate in.

Comment: @DavidK yeah it makes sense .actually before posting question here i was doing a research on red flags for scam jobs and almost everywhere it was about grammar and English in emails.but as you said none of us are native English speaker so it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @DavidK It would be a red flag if they claimed to be a big (international) corporation, as they could pay a proper HR person with English skills for international recruitment, but for such a small startup company indeed it is not in itself. (Being a small company on the other hand obviously comes with some stability risk but that's another topic...)

Comment: Is this employment or a contract? If contract work, I would expect much more than 50% increase over employment to cover taxes, insurance, retirement etc. If employment, will you get payslips? Any taxes withheld? A relieving letter at the end of the employment? The more they are planning to conform to all labor and employment law, the more likely it is to be legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

In the comment you said the following:

> it was in one of the costliest 5 star hotels in India.

As to how you met the individual. If it were me, I would follow up if he actually had a room there or not. What I would have done is called the hotel and tell them if they can leave a message for guest [insert name]. If they say no such person is booked at the hotel, then you can get suspicious.

> What are the things that I should look out for (red flags)?

Go with your guts. If something sounds off or doesn't sound right, don't do it. If they start to ask for money or information of something, then simply don't do it and walk away.